# Deleting kudu range partitions less than the given string

Tags: impala, kudu, apache-kudu

I want to delete all Kudu RANGE partitions from the kudu table which has partition value less than a given date string. I am using following query but it's not working. Can someone please suggest what is the workaround.

```sql
alter table test_table drop if exists range partition values < '2010-01-31';
```

My Impala version is 2.6x and it appears to not work with '<' comparison. I can't use '=' because as it's going to be done dynamically and i need one single query to wipe off all empty kudu partitions before the passed date string.

Edit 1: Work-around I implemented. So, I had to write the script to fetch unique partition values and dynamically create the SQL which would give the same output after execution.

```bash
 drop_partition_query=''
 read -d '' drop_query <<EOF
select distinct partition_date from test_table where partition_date < '2021-01-01' group by partition_date
EOF
partitions_to_drop=$(${IMPALA_SHELL} -B -q "${drop_query}" --quiet "--output_delimiter=\n" 2>/dev/null)
partitions_array=( $partitions_to_drop )
for (( p=0; p< ${#partitions_array[@]}; p++ ))
do
   drop_partition_query+="ALTER TABLE test_table DROP RANGE PARTITION VALUE='${partitions_array[$p]}';"
done

# drop_partition_query is the sql that should be executed to drop the partitions.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that on your version you cannot use such syntax, looks like this feature was added in Impala 2.8

[Docu](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_alter_table.html)

> To drop or alter multiple partitions:
>
> In Impala 2.8 and higher, the expression for the partition clause with
> a DROP or SET operation can include comparison operators such as <,
> IN, or BETWEEN, and Boolean operators such as AND and OR.
>
> For example, you might drop a group of partitions corresponding to a
> particular date range after the data "ages out":
>
> alter table historical_data drop partition (year < 1995); alter table
> historical_data drop partition (year = 1996 and month between 1 and
> 6);
>
> For tables with multiple partition keys columns, you can specify
> multiple conditions separated by commas, and the operation only
> applies to the partitions that match all the conditions (similar to
> using an AND clause):
>
> alter table historical_data drop partition (year < 1995, last_name
> like 'A%');
>
> This technique can also be used to change the file format of groups of
> partitions, as part of an ETL pipeline that periodically consolidates
> and rewrites the underlying data files in a different file format:
>
> alter table fast_growing_data partition (year = 2016, month in
> (10,11,12)) set fileformat parquet;

Here is ticket in which it was added if you want to take a look: [Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-1654)

Not sure how to handle it, maybe you can write some script/spark shell code which will list all partitions and choose only does one which you want and concat them into one query which your Impala can handle

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, i have already written a script to execute set of add partition statements for each partition in one batch. Will update the question with the current work around used.